# What other recognized detective story categories are there beyond the "locked room mystery"?

Tags: genre, mystery-novels

I'm an avid reader of cozy detective fiction (C. Auguste Dupin, Sherlock Holmes, Father Brown, &c.) and noticed naturally that certain categories exist (or that's the notion I have) even within that single subgenre (my preferred genre is: cozy quaint traditional golden age detective fiction, I'm no expert for anything contemporary).

But when searching for recognized categories all I can turn up is the well known "locked room mystery". I'm not aiming at the distinction that is made by realism/brutalness/viewpoint/period; i.e. this is not about "hardboiled vs cozy" or "historical vs contemporary" or the like.

My own categories I identified up until now are thus:

- **Locked room mystery**: something happened (usually a murder) in a locked room or otherwise inaccessible place. The case is therefore impossible, yet it happened.
  Examples: Auguste Dupin: *The Murders in the Rue Morgue*, Poirot: *Murder at Styles*, Father Brown: *The Wrong Shape*
- **Remote detective**: The detective solves the case without personally investigating the crime scene solely by using the information that was provided to him second-hand, usually sitting in his armchair. The detective may be remote regarding space and time, i.e. may solve a crime that happened long ago.
  Examples: Father Brown: *The Broken Sword*, Auguste Dupin: *The Mystery of Marie Rogêt*
- **Treasure hunt**: The detective is literally on a treasure hunt.
  Examples: Sherlock Holmes: *Musgrave Ritual*, E. A. Poe: *The Gold-Bug*
- **One after another**: A group of people happen to be stranded together, they are killed off one by one. Usually the murderer is among the group.
  Examples: A. Christie: *And Then There Were None*, *Death Comes as the End*
- **Spooky story**: the story contains elements that are aimed to suggest scary supernatural/preternatural agents are involved, like ghosts, animated wax works, hell-hounds and werewolves. Usually to be debunked in the conclusion.
  Examples: Sherlock Holmes: *Hound of the Baskervilles*, Father Brown: *The Ghost of Gideon Wise*
- **Well hidden object**: the detective has to find out through his ingenuity the hiding place of some well hidden object.
  Examples: Sherlock Holmes: *A Scandal in Bohemia*, Auguste Dupin: *The Purloined Letter*

I have to re-read some stories and maybe add further entries to the list.

Are there any texts/resources available online or in print that deal with this kind of (rather academical) categorization?

Comment: What are you looking for? Feedback on your categories (probably too opinion-based)? Academic classifications of detective novels (might be too broad or have no answer)? Non-academic classifications of detective novels (probably opinion-based/too broad)? Our personal categories of detective novels (definitely too opinion-based)?

Comment: @bobble I don't think my observation is unique and that therefore some academic coverage of those recurring plot devices that arose with the detective fiction genre must exist. I'm quite keen on reading any such literary meta material. By posting this question I hope to find the lead for further reading.